# Fallout 3 never launches

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-3

I am unable to start Fallout 3 Game of the Year Edition from Steam.  I click to play the game in Steam, the launcher opens and I click play.  Nothing happens.  My steam status goes back to "Online" from "Playing Fallout 3".  I've verified the game cache and meet the requirements.

- Windows 8.1 64bit
- Intel Core i7-4790k
- 16GB RAM
- 2x Nvidia GTX 660 (SLI) (Latest Drivers)
- Steam Latest Stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam fails to install one of the required prerequisites for Fallout 3 to run: The Games for Windows Live client.  Download and install the [Games for Windows Live Client (Microsoft Download)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5549) then Fallout 3 should start.

Comment: Try 'verifying integrity of game cache' and updating the game, GFWL support was removed entirely

Comment: Clearly not, I just installed it today and it wouldn't run without the client.  I figured something may have not downloaded correctly so I tried verifying the cache.

Comment: Wierd. I did just the same thing two days ago, and it ran fine. (Until I started messing with mods of course :P)

Comment: Also: I noticed your system specs, you might wanna restrict Fallout to 2 cores if you haven't already: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10041/28182

Comment: Thanks for that. It was the first thing I did after having the launcher determine my graphic settings.

Comment: Cool. Sometimes I with Bethesda would just push an update with some of these fixes haha